# multiple text colors in jQuery Tooltip

Tags: jquery-ui, colors, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm trying to get some words in a jQuery tooltip text, another colour. Is this possible? I would like to give the words 'CONTROL PANEL BUTTON' another colour. I already give the tooltip a custom class. Can I for instance use two classes for different parts of the tooltip text?
Here's my script:

```
$("#ControlBTN").tooltip({
    content: "CONTROL PANEL BUTTON<br><br>Click to show or hide the Fluid Control Panel.",
    tooltipClass: "ui-tooltip_trans"
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can see here, https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content that you can use HTML in your Custom Content. This means you can wrap words with HTML and use the Class attribute to change the color of that element.

Comment: Hi Twisty. Thank you very much for you help :-)